# How to get a List of Virtual Machines in azure using rest apis?

Tags: azure

Help to find this solution.
I want to list all the virtual machines in my all hosted services.

Comment: Have you looked at Azure Service Management API - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx?

Comment: Yes I did but could not find solution for it.
I looked at azure java sdk too but could not find same!!

Comment: If you search around, you will find many examples of how to consume this API and list virtual machines. Please try implementing it and then come back with specific issues you are running into.

Comment: Thanks for time and suggestions.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx
They have examples for operations on virtual machines.

It's not that complicated in AWS to do this using AWS java sdk.
is azure java sdk still under beta version? or they do not want it use friendly!!

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/06/23/authenticating-azure-resource-management-rest-api-requests-using-java.aspx

This has an example on how to get list of VM's using ARM REST API's.